# C# while loop with range 0 - 5

Tags: c#, validation, loops, while-loop

Ii am new to c# and trying to create a validation through use of a while loop with the range from 0 - 5, my problem is that when this range is used it also accepts string characters, how can I stop this and only allow integers 0 - 5?

my code so far

```
   static void Main()

    {
        int Rateing1, Rateing2;

         Console.Write("Please rate from 0 - 5:   ");
         Rateing1 = valid_rating();

         Console.Write("\nPlease rate from 0 - 5:    ");
         Rateing2 = valid_rating();

         Console.WriteLine("\nRateing1 is {0}", Rateing1);
         Console.WriteLine("Rateing2 is {0}", Rateing2);
     }

    static int valid_rating()

          {
            int rating;

            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rating);
                while (rating < 0 || rating > 5)
                     {
                       Console.Write("\nInvalid Input, please input an integer from 0 - 5");
                       Console.Write("\nPlease enter new rating:   ");
                       int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rating);
                     } 
            return rating;
          }
```

Comment: is "valid_entry" a string? can you show the things youve declared ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out rating) || rating < 0 || rating > 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, please input an integer from 0 - 5");
    Console.Write("Please enter new rating:   ");
}
```

That is, you want the user to enter input again if *any* of the following is true:

- They entered an invalid number.
- The number they entered is less than 0.
- The number they entered is greater than 5.

Your problem was that you were not using the value returned by `int.TryParse` (which is a `bool` indicating success or failure); you were simply using the value written to `rating` which, in the case of failure, is 0 (and `!(0 < 0)`).